# get unique values, out of a list with uniq utility, when data are separated by |

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, uniq

I have a list of values, that may have in them special characters, all kind of characters.

```
jusewe@somemail.com
Denver Occupy|another name|metadata
another name
metadata
```

I need a way with `uniq` utility in `linux`, or `sed`, `awk`, to have as output:
unique values from above list:

```
jusewe@somemail.com
Denver Occupy
another name
metadata
```

What i have tried:

```
uniq -u test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uniq will work only if repeated lines are adjacent

will give uniq values sorted

```
sort -u test
```

EDIT: to split lines on `|`

```
tr '|' '\n' < test | sort -u
```

Comment: you did not see my question, i am afraid. each row may have many values separated by the "|" separator, so i need to get unique values, based not on what each row has, but based on all values found in the file

Comment: just add `tr '|' '\n'` before, updating

Comment: and the above would be case sensitive, i suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne "s/|/\n/p" test |sort |uniq
```

enjoy

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.